# Activating CSS through a HTML button press

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering if you can activate some CSS through an HTML button press or scrolling to a certain point. It's preferred if it's through JS.

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: Yes, I know that but how to do it?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't include a working snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a wrapper class:

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button")
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.body.classList.add("red")
})
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Stackoverflow is nice!</h1>
<p>Great website!</p>
<button>Change CSS</button>
```

- **Create a button** which listens for a user action.
- When the button is **clicked add a class to the body element**.
- Use **this class to apply different css** rules.

You can build a dark theme with that for example.

Answer (score 0):

As previously said by @Lain, it is indeed possible.
something like `someElement.classList.add()` or `someElement.classlist.toggle()`
[MDN Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)